# assign list values to another list

Tags: python, list

I have two lists of the same length, one containing integers and one floats. I want to assign every float number to an integer number - **relatively**.

By **relative**, I mean:

- **higher** integer numbers are supposed to have a **higher chance** to receive a **low** float number
- **lower** integer numbers are supposed to have a **lower chance** to receive a **low** float number

For assigning it's enough to append the float numbers to a result array, so that `integers[index]` matches the assigned `result[index]`.

Since I'm talking about **chances**, I cannot simply order one list descending and one list ascending and match them.

I'm not quite sure how to approach my problem. I'm looking for some functions/modules I haven't heard of - or as always preferred: pure python build in solutions :)

```
#INDICES:   0    1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9  

integers = [5,   5,   2,   4,   3,   1,   4,   5,   2,   3  ]
floats =   [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5]


#possible result (could be different):
result =   [0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.8, 0.6, 0.1, 0.3, 0.5]

#the result values are assigned to the integers at the same index
```

As you can see, in the result example, the `result[9]==0.5` is assigned to `integers[9]==3`, while `result[6]==0.6` is assigned to `integers[6]==4`. Which is an exception to the rest of the list, since in general higher floats were assigned to lower integers.

Comment: How high is a high number? High absolutely, or high within a given list?

Comment: Well, I think the best would be to rely on the list itself, to find a general solution. So 'high' would be 5 for integer and 0.8 for floats in my example. But given other list, this might defer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should do the trick:

```
import random

def shuffle(ints, floats):

    new_ints = list(sorted(ints))
    new_floats = list(sorted(floats))

    def weight(x, n):
        # implement your own weight system here
        # maybe `n+x` - just make sure that as
        # x increases the weight increases
        return x

    def gen_weights(n):
        return [weight(x,n) for x in range(1,n+1)]

    result = []
    while new_ints:
        i = random.choices(range(len(new_ints)), gen_weights(len(new_ints)))[0]
        result.append((new_ints.pop(0), new_floats.pop(i)))

    new_result = []
    for x in ints:
        for i, (j, f) in enumerate(result):
            if j == x:
                new_result.append(f)
                del result[i]
                break
    return new_result

random.seed(1)

in1 = [5,   5,   2,   4,   3,   1,   4,   5,   2,   3  ]
in2 = [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5]

result = shuffle(in1, in2)
print(result)
```

Output:

```
[0.3, 0.1, 0.8, 0.5, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.2, 0.6, 0.5]
```

---

Essentially, it makes a sorted copy of both lists, then creates a set of weights for each float to determine how likely they are to be chosen. It removes that index from the set of floats, and chooses the first value of the set of ints, and stores it in the results list, deleting the items from the sets of ints and floats.

Finally, the function goes through each item in the original ints list, and finds a corresponding integer value in the results list. It removes that value, and appends it to the output (`new_result`) list.

---

If you don't like the linear weights system, replace the `return x` value in the `weight` function with any other **increasing** function. Ensure that higher values of `x` have higher return values.

---

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a relatively simple approach:

```
import random

STD_DEV = 2

integers = sorted([5, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3], reverse=True)
floats = sorted([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5])

results = []
for i in range(0, len(integers)): 
    noisy_index = min(max(int(random.gauss(i, STD_DEV)), 0), len(floats)-1)
    results.append(floats[noisy_index])

print(results)
# [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7]
```

It first sorts the integers descending and then the floats ascending, then loops over the integer indices and determines the index of the float value to choose by sampling from a gaussian distribution around that index value. The STD_DEV value will give you a control on how often further indexes are chosen...I chose STD_DEV=2 because it seemed to perform reasonably (i.e. it wasn't likely index=0 would jump to index=9).

Note that this is really a *relative* weighting approach. The sorted integer index value is what establishes the *most likely* float to be chosen, but it would behave the same if the first two numbers were `5, 5...` or if they were `500, 5...`.

**EDIT**: if you want the integer values to have some weight beyond their relative ordering, one approach would be to scale the standard deviation of the guassian distribution based on the value. Here is one approach (of many ways you could do this) that just scales the standard deviation based on the distance of the integer value from the mean:

```
import random

BASE_STD_DEV = 2

integers = sorted([5, 5, 2, 4, 3, 1, 4, 5, 2, 3], reverse=True)
floats = sorted([0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.3, 0.3, 0.7, 0.6, 0.8, 0.5, 0.5])

avg_int = sum(integers)/len(integers)
max_dist = max([abs(i - avg_int) for i in integers])

results = []
for i, integer in enumerate(integers):
    factor = 1 - abs(integer - avg_int) / max_dist
    std_dev = BASE_STD_DEV * factor
    noisy_index = min(max(int(random.gauss(i, std_dev)), 0), len(floats)-1)
    results.append(floats[noisy_index])

print(results)
# [0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0.2, 0.5, 0.3, 0.5, 0.5, 0.8, 0.7]
```

You could easily adjust this to perhaps have a minimum standard deviation or minimum/maximum `factor`, as currently the values on the extremes would have no standard deviation.

Comment: Love this approach, especially since it provides control over the standard deviation. I'll run some test with Ed Ward his solution, too, before accepting an answer. For now I'm a little in a conflict with your solution since it's ignoring the absolute values of the integers, as you pointed out yourself.

Comment: I'll give that some thought. One quick hack that comes to mind: you could scale the STD_DEV value based on the value of the integer. So a really large integer could have a smaller STD_DEV (narrower distribution to choose from) and would be more likely to stay at the lower indexed float values.

Comment: Actually you'd probably want to narrow the distribution based on distance from the mean value, instead of just favoring large or small.

Comment: @MaxSchlesag I gave an alternative that shows one way to take the integer value into account. Let me know if that helps.